# Application Cache - net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: caching, manifest, application-cache

I'm trying to build an offline web form. It only uses jQuery and twitter bootstrap as external resources. I've tried to cache them but when I refresh offline I get `net::ERR_FAILED` for both jQuery and bootstrap. I'm very new to AppCache so any help is appreciated. Here is my manifest and where I'm including things in my html:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

../style-bootstrap.css
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

NETWORK:
*
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" manifest="/includes/pouchcontacts.manifest" type="text/cache-manifest">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Contacts [OFFLINE]</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-bootstrap.css">
</head>
```